# I cannot solve this problem -> Type mismatch: inferred type is List ... but Collection<Fragment> was expected

Tags: android, kotlin

Type mismatch: inferred type is List<{ActivityResultCaller & ComponentCallbacks & HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory & OnCreateContextMenuListener & SavedStateRegistryOwner & ViewModelStoreOwner}> but Collection was expected

```kotlin
package com.example.a220402

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.example.a220402.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var testViewAdapter: TestViewAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        initAdapter()
        initBottomNavi()
    }

    private fun initAdapter() {
        val fragmentList = listOf(ProfileFragment(), HomeFragment(), CameraFragment())
        testViewAdapter = TestViewAdapter(this)
        testViewAdapter.fragments.addAll(fragmentList)

        binding.vpMain.adapter = testViewAdapter
    }

    private fun initBottomNavi() {
        binding.vpMain.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                binding.bnvMain.menu.getItem(position).isChecked = true
            }
        })

        binding.bnvMain.setOnItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.menu_profile -> {
                    binding.vpMain.currentItem = FIRST_FRAGMENT
                    return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.menu_home -> {
                    binding.vpMain.currentItem = SECOND_FRAGMENT
                    return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
                }
                else -> {
                    binding.vpMain.currentItem = THIRD_FRAGMENT
                    return@setOnItemSelectedListener true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val FIRST_FRAGMENT = 0
        const val SECOND_FRAGMENT = 1
        const val THIRD_FRAGMENT = 2
    }
}
```

I got problem 'Type mismatch: inferred type is List<{ActivityResultCaller & ComponentCallbacks & HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory & OnCreateContextMenuListener & SavedStateRegistryOwner & ViewModelStoreOwner}> but Collection was expected' in line 24.
Please give me advice to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: you need to use typed version of `listOf`

Comment: Whatever ``fragments`` is in ``testViewAdapter``, it's expecting a raw ``Collection`` for some reason. Are you using a Kotlin type for that, like a ``mutableList`` or ``mutableSet``?